# Recursive functions with math operators

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to build a function that takes two natural numbers n and m and returns a tuple of the squares of all the natural numbers starting with n and ending with m-1. I am able to decide if the function should return if m is smaller than n, but it shouldn't crash or return some sort of error message. So squares_tuple(3,7) returns (9,16,25,36) and rec_range(10,11) returns (100,).  Also, I do not want to use range(), map(), loops, or lists.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def squares_tuple(n,m):
"""takes two nat nums n and m and returns a tuple of the squares of all the
natural numbers starting with n and ending with m-1

nat, nat -> tuple of natural numbers"""
   if m >= 0:
       return 0
   else:
       return squares_tuple(n - 1, ) + (n**m, )
```

Kind of stuck at this point...

Comment: Don't you want that to be `if m <= 0:`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def squares_tuple(n, m):
    return (n * n, ) + squares_tuple(n + 1, m) if n < m else ()
```

Example:

```
>>> squares_tuple(0, 6)
(0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25)
>>> squares_tuple(3, 7)
(9, 16, 25, 36)
```

Comment: @AdamSmith You cannot add a list to a tuple so you cannot cast your return type to a tuple.

Comment: @Shashank bah, you're right. I'm terrible with recursing functions. Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Does this have to be a recursive function? If not then the best solution is:

```
def squares_tuple(start, stop):
    return tuple([num**2 for num in range(start, stop)])
```

Comment: You don't actually need to create a temporary list: `return tuple(num**2 for num in range(start, stop))`. [_since python 2.4_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

Comment: @BillLynch I haven't profiled, but in a few of those kinds of "building from a completed list" functions using the list comp is actually faster. see the comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9060697/3058609)

Comment: @AdamSmith Look at my test here: http://repl.it/f2h Adding the tuples is doable in a lower amount of time. Note that I created both the lists and the tuples in the setup phase so I'm only testing the add operator time. (Creating tuples is also faster than creating lists)